# Are the supernatural characters of Straub's Ghost Story further explored/explained in any other book or movie?

Tags: ghost-story

Peter Straub's literary horror novel had a supernatural being who referred to "herself" as a manitou and apparently could transform humans into what we have called vampires and/or werewolves -- multiple characters besides the uber manitou have died and then returned, interacting with humans over many decades. The main two are brothers named Gregory and Fenny Bates.

I do not see in the novel where much explanation is given -- whether the "deal" is struck prior to death or more likely it seems somehow after death or really exactly the nature of the brothers. They live without changing appearance for many years -- Fenny was a strange kid in a one-room school being taught by one of the main characters and he simply dropped dead, while Gregory died by other means.

The book drops tantalizing occasional details about these transformed humans; Gregory is quite articulate although it is unclear if his creator is speaking through him or not.

So my question is, besides the novel (and the movie made from it), did Straub employ these characters in any other work?

Comment: I've edited this to stop it from being a list/ recommendation question.

Comment: *"Ricky Hawthorne is mentioned in the author's 1983 novel Floating Dragon, in which it is stated that he is the uncle of a victim in the latter book. The town of Milburn briefly appears in Koko, published in 1988."* - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_Story_(Straub_novel)

Comment: @Valorum The synopsis of FD sounds like the author intended the supernatural aspect to potentially be related to that found in Ghost Story. There is also a character whose first name is Bates. And the theme of a town crumbling. Interesting.